# How call back function of a function works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
$.map( [ 0, 1, 2 ], function( n ) {
  return n > 0 ? n + 1 : null;
});
```

> Out Put: [ 2, 3 ]

I know `$.map` `Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.`([Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)).
What I want to know how `call back function` in a `.map` works(internal implentation)?
One possible answer could be

1. `.map` has some loop which passes each element of array to `call back method`, that return some value.
2. `.map` manage each value return from `call back method`.In this case push in some internal array.
3. At the end of loop `.map` return array.
   **EDIT**

> But I am not sure how it works, is it works as I explained??

Comment: Here -> [http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.map](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.1.3&fn=jQuery.map)

Comment: Your assumption is generally correct. See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L358

Comment: I honestly did not look at any of your comment until after I answered. But yeah, basically what you all said :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I am not sure is this how it works??

Yes, that's basically how it works. Full details, as always, in [the source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L358) *(that line number will rot over time...)*. Currently, it looks like this:

```
map: function( elems, callback, arg ) {
    var value,
        i = 0,
        length = elems.length,
        isArray = isArraylike( elems ),
        ret = [];

    // Go through the array, translating each of the items to their new values
    if ( isArray ) {
        for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
            value = callback( elems[ i ], i, arg );

            if ( value != null ) {
                ret.push( value );
            }
        }

    // Go through every key on the object,
    } else {
        for ( i in elems ) {
            value = callback( elems[ i ], i, arg );

            if ( value != null ) {
                ret.push( value );
            }
        }
    }

    // Flatten any nested arrays
    return concat.apply( [], ret );
},
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is no better way to check than looking at the source code

```
function (elems, callback, arg) {
    var value, i = 0,
        length = elems.length,
        isArray = isArraylike(elems),
        ret = [];

    // Go through the array, translating each of the items to their new values
    if (isArray) {
        for (; i < length; i++) {
            value = callback(elems[i], i, arg);

            if (value != null) {
                ret.push(value);
            }
        }

        // Go through every key on the object,
    } else {
        for (i in elems) {
            value = callback(elems[i], i, arg);

            if (value != null) {
                ret.push(value);
            }
        }
    }

    // Flatten any nested arrays
    return concat.apply([], ret);
}
```

1. Yes, whether its an `Array` version or object, it is looping and calling the `callback` to set the value
2. Yes, for both loops, the value is *pushed*
3. Yes, it is returning a **flattened** array by calling `concat`